# Parse JSON like syntax to ruby object

Tags: ruby, parsing

Simple parser which turned out to be much harder than i thought. I need a string parser to convert nested fields to ruby object. In my case api response will only return desired fields.

Given

```
Parser.parse "album{name, photo{name, picture, tags}}, post{id}"
```

Desired output or similar

```
{album: [:name, photo: [:name, :picture, :tags]], post: [:id]}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think it will be that easy. Where are you getting such string from?

Comment: This is pretty much the use case for parser generators such as as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) - if this is a custom syntax your options are to either hand-craft a parser or to use a parser generator such as ANTLR.

Comment: @Surya I want to implement in my api the same syntax for selecting fields as facebook. Since objects are nested, syntax should also allow that.

Comment: @antulik What Facebook (and others like Spotify and GitHub) is using there is a standard language called GraphQL. There is a pretty complete Ruby gem also called [graphql](http://graphql-ruby.org/) which allows you to  implement your schema, the querying and many other aspects in your app.

Comment: As I said, you should have a look at the [graphql gem](http://graphql-ruby.org/) which (among other things) implements a parser for the [GraphQL language](http://graphql.org/). Using this gem, you should be able to build your API as GraphQL endpoint without having to implement everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote my own solution

```
module Parser
  extend self

  def parse str
    parse_list(str).map do |i|
      extract_item_fields i
    end
  end

  def extract_item_fields item
    field_name, fields_str = item.scan(/(.+?){(.+)}/).flatten

    if field_name.nil?
      item
    else
      fields = parse_list fields_str
      result = fields.map { |field| extract_item_fields(field) }

      { field_name => result }
    end
  end

  def parse_list list
    return list if list.nil?
    list.concat(',').scan(/([^,{}]+({.+?})?),/).map(&:first).map(&:strip)
  end
end

str = 'album{name, photo{name, picture, tags}}, post{id}'
puts Parser.parse(str).inspect
# => [{"album"=>["name", {"photo"=>["name", "picture", "tags"]}]}, {"post"=>["id"]}]
```